# Visual C++ won't accept hOut

Tags: c++, console, formatting

Visual C++ won't accept hOut  (identifier is undefined). I tried to search and added all the needed libraries but it still won't work. For my knowledge the libraries I need to include are windows.h, cstdlib and stdlib.h This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stack>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class karta
{
public:
    karta(string litery[], bool licznik[][13], string kolory[]);
    ~karta();
    void WypiszKarte();

private:
    string litera;
    string kolor;
};

karta::karta(string litery[], bool licznik[][13], string kolory[])
{
    bool karta_zmieniona;
    do
    {
        karta_zmieniona = 0;

        int losowana_litera = 0 + rand() % 13;
        int losowany_kolor = 0 + rand() % 4;

        if (licznik[losowany_kolor][losowana_litera]) //jesli mozemy jeszcze wylosowac daną litere
        {
            licznik[losowany_kolor][losowana_litera];
            litera = litery[losowana_litera];
            kolor = kolory[losowany_kolor];
            karta_zmieniona = true;
        }





    } while (!karta_zmieniona);
}

void karta::WypiszKarte()
{
    cout << setw(2) << kolor << litera;
}

karta::~karta()
{

}

int main()
{
    string litery[13] = { "A" ,"1" ,"2" ,"3" ,"4" ,"5" ,"6" ,"7" ,"8" ,"9" ,"J" ,"Q" ,"K" };
    string kolor[4] = { "+" , "-" , "*" , "=" };
    bool licznik[4][13];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            licznik[i][j] = { true };
        }

    }

    vector<vector<karta>> plansza;

    vector<karta> rzad;




    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            rzad.push_back(karta(litery, licznik, kolor));
        }

        plansza.push_back(rzad);

        rzad.clear();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            rzad.push_back(karta(litery, licznik, kolor));
        }

        plansza.push_back(rzad);

        rzad.clear();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < plansza[i].size(); i++)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut, BACKGROUND_RED);
        cout << " " << i+1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            plansza[j][i].WypiszKarte();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");



    return 0;
}
```

Why could this be?

Comment: And you got `hOut` from where actually?

Comment: You *do* know that variables needs to be declared, defined and initialized before you use them?

Comment: read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, which links to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which has your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hOut is undefined and uninitialized if you didn't define it in `"stdafx.h"`,(Because the other header files are in the standard library, they will never define hOut) if so,  add code:

`HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);`

before your code :

`SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut, BACKGROUND_RED);`

(note : hOut is just a varible we define, you can change it to any legal name).